# Map data attribution requirement

Tags: leaflet

I have created an app that uses `Leaflet` map as part of it.

I saw multiple documentations of how I should attribute it but I couldn't figure out whether I got it all or something is missing.

Right now it looks as follows:

[image]

Where I link to:

1. https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/
2. https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright
3. https://docs.mapbox.com/

Is there anything more that should appear on it?

Is there any terms of use for these maps that I can read or the only requirements are to give attributes/linking?

The code im using is:

```
String Map_HTML = "<html>\n" +
        "<head>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    <title>Quick Start - Leaflet</title>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />\n" +
        "    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\">\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    <link rel=\"shortcut icon\" type=\"image/x-icon\" href=\"docs/images/favicon.ico\" />\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    <link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css\" integrity=\"sha512-puBpdR0798OZvTTbP4A8Ix/l+A4dHDD0DGqYW6RQ+9jxkRFclaxxQb/SJAWZfWAkuyeQUytO7+7N4QKrDh+drA==\" crossorigin=\"\"/>\n" +
        "    <script src=\"https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js\" integrity=\"sha512-QVftwZFqvtRNi0ZyCtsznlKSWOStnDORoefr1enyq5mVL4tmKB3S/EnC3rRJcxCPavG10IcrVGSmPh6Qw5lwrg==\" crossorigin=\"\"></script>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "<style>\n" +
        "body {\n" +
        "padding: 0;\n" +
        "margin: 0;\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "html, body, #map {\n" +
        "height: 100%;\n" +
        "width: 100%;\n" +
        "}\n" +
        "</style>\n" +
        "</head>\n" +
        "<body>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "<div id=\"mapid\" style=\"width: " + dpWidth + "px; height: " + dpHeight * 0.3 + "px;\"></div>\n" +
        "<script>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "var mymap = L.map('mapid',{zoomControl: false}).setView([" + Lat + ", " + Lon + "], 10);\n" +
        "\n" +
        "    L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=......', {\n" +
        "    maxZoom: 18,\n" +
        "    attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href=\"https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright\">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +\n" +
        "    '<a href=\"https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/\">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +\n" +
        "    'Imagery &copy <a href=\"https://www.mapbox.com/\">Mapbox</a>',\n" +
        "    id: 'mapbox.streets'\n" +
        "    }).addTo(mymap);\n" +
        "\n" +
        "mymap.attributionControl.setPosition('topright')\n" +
        "L.control.zoom({\n" +
        "position: 'bottomright'\n" +
        "}).addTo(mymap);\n" +
        "L.marker([" + Lat + ", " + Lon + "]).addTo(mymap)\n" +
        "    .bindPopup(\"<b>My Location</b>\").openPopup();\n" +
        "\n" +
        "L.circle([" + Lat + ", " + Lon + "], " + Radius + ", {\n" +
        "    color: 'red',\n" +
        "    fillColor: '#8275FE',\n" +
        "    fillOpacity: 0.4,\n" +
        "    weight: '0'\n" +
        "}).addTo(mymap);\n" +
        "\n" +
        "\n" +
        "var popup = L.popup();\n" +
        "\n" +
        "</script>\n" +
        "\n" +
        "</body>\n" +
        "</html>";
```

Also, if I changes the tiles into:

```
https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}
```

Does it mean I can remove the attributes to mapbox?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the data (e.g. tiles) that you display on your map. The Leaflet attribution itself is optional.

> Is there any terms of use for these maps that I can read

Yes there is. Again, it should be specified by the source of your data.

OSM data requires attribution with a link as you show. Many other tile services are based on OSM (e.g. mapbox), hence the requirement to attribute OSM besides their own service.

Each service has its own specific requirement, so make sure to properly read their terms.

As for CC-BY-SA, either some of your data is licensed under this one, or it is useless.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I added the HTML im using in my app. From my understanding I only use mapbox tiles in their?

Comment: From the code you share now, indeed it looks like the main data source you use is mapbox. You can find information about their attribution requirement for example on their [help page](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/how-mapbox-works/attribution/). As for your Marker and Circle, it might depend what source you use. Indeed, if you replace your Tile Layer to use OSM directly, you no longer need the mapbox attribution. But make sure to comply with OSM terms (in particular reasonable tile usage).

Comment: From my understanding the marker and circle are just part of Leafjet where I can play with color and so on, no?

Comment: If your Lat, Lon and Radius data do not come from licensed source, then you are fine.